# Should I use the setInterval function to repeat this or a Jquery repeat function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, setinterval

Just curious, I have this function:

```
    function detectChanges() 
{                   
    sendAjax('reload', num_rows, '',
        function(data) 
        { 
            $('#container').html(data);                  
        });
}
```

Write it:

```
   detectChanges();
```

Should I just use setInterval to repeat this function every 5 seconds or is there a better, cleaner jQuery alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but you probably don't want to be polling something every 5 seconds, ESPECIALLY if you're going to make an AJAX call to the server every 5 seconds.

Perhaps you can use `jQuery.change()` - http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: The only reason I am making an ajax call to the server every 5 seconds is because I need the page to reload the content on the page

Comment: @TaylorMac does it change every 5 seconds? or it MIGHT change every 5 seconds? I'd suggest giving the user a choice atleast.

Answer (score 1):

setInterval is pretty clean. You might actually want to use setTimeout, and call that at the end of each response to the AJAX call. That way if a request takes more than 5 seconds, you won't have them overlap.

Comment: Im sorry but how would I use setTimeout on a 'wrapper' function? I am unfamiliar with that function

Comment: currently I have just been using clearInterval to stop it... setTimeout is better to use for this?

Comment: I've edited to be more clear. I just meant that you should use setTimeout to invoke method once, and then when you get the response, call setTimeout again to repeat the process.

Comment: @Taylor if your setInterval is always being cleared after a single invocation, you might as well use setTimeout, since you're not actually taking advantage of setIntervals recurring nature.